# OpenVPN & Routing

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

im stuck with routing my openvpn setup

My Central Openvpn Server is in the Internet (VPS). He is using 10.1.0.1 as vpn ip

My Home-LAN (10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0) which has a Client on 10.0.0.11 and got 10.1.0.2 as vpn. Static route is set via dhcp in homenet

Home --> VPS works perfectly

but i do not get VPS->Home to works

```
ping from 10.1.0.1 to 10.1.0.2 works
ping from 10.1.0.1 to 10.0.0.11 NOT works
ping from 10.1.0.1 to 10.0.0.xx NOT works
ping from 10.0.0.xx to 10.1.0.1 works

$ip route get 10.0.0.10
10.0.0.10 via 10.1.0.2 dev tun0 src 10.1.0.1
  cache
```

ip forwarding is enabled on local client

```
root@local:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0


root@on:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        10.1.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
XX.yy.168.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

What am i missing?